# Python Tkinter - How do I handle an undetermined time user input?

Tags: python, tkinter, user-input

I started with Python a few months ago and now I wanted to get into tkinter. Now I am at a point where I do not know what to do at all.

2 source files are important.
file A -> all widgets, which are displayed in the window
file B -> here are functions to create in file A e.g. a label and use commands

```py
#file A example
root = fileB.getwindow()
frame = fileB.getframe(root)
#...
#...

#file B example
def getwindow():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Hello World")
    root.geometry("720x720")
    return root

#getframe, getlabel and so on...
# ...
# ...
```

In my program the user can load a *.csv file via a file dialog. The problem I have is that the user loads the file at an unknown time.
When my command triggers and the user selects his csv file, then the path to the file is only in the function.

```py
def filedialog():
    path = tk.filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Select File", 
                                         filetypes=(("csv files","*.csv"), ("all files", "*.*")))
```

After selecting the *.csv file, a table should be created, for which I need the path. I could also put the table in the filedialog function, but that doesn't help me so much, because the other widgets need some information from the *.csv file.

A general idea on how to proceed would be enough for me. I hope I could provide enough information to make the problem clear.

[Here is a picture to visually imagine the program.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZs0j.png)

Comment: What about returning the path variable from `filedialog()`. Otherwise you could also make your functions members of a class and make the `path` a member of an instance (`self.path`)...

Comment: @angelogro Thanks for the suggestion. After thinking about it for a while, I like the class idea more and more.